# delimited txt file to array? then update mysql PHP

Tags: php, delimited

How'd I go about reading a tab delimited .txt file and then coding it so it puts each column of data(that is seperated with a tab) into a php variable.

for example....

`505050 somedata moredata`

and then, writing these variables to

`$id
$somedata
$moredata`

I read into fgetcsv and making an array although it seemed to make the whole line an array i need to split it into variables so that i can write it to individual columns in the MySQL database,

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks so much...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) will be the most efficient way to split this into named variables:

```
list($id, $somedata, $moredata) = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t");
```

However, you do not need to have them as named variables in order to insert them in MySQL, you can just use the raw array returned by `fgetcsv()`:

```
$row = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t");

$query = "
  INSERT INTO `tablename`
    (`id`, `somedata`, `moredata`)
  VALUES
    ('{$row[0]}', '{$row[1]}', '{$row[2]}')
";
```

Don't forget to escape the data before using it in a query ;-)

Comment: Ah, I failed in my answer. Never knew about fgetcsv. +1 for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll look into using explode!

Answer (score 0):

[explode()](http://php.net/explode) will split a string. Try this:

`list($id, $somedata, $moredata) = explode("\t", $string);`

Where `$string` is the string you want to split. For more info about explode() and list(), just look up on php.net.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answers! I'll look into using the explode function!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: DaveRandom's answer is better.